# How to display text in a format

Tags: java, android, xml, validation, android-activity

```
    display a text in format  

    email.setText(text);
```

1. List item

   text="1. You won’t feel drained or tired if you drink fluids and have an honest meal."
           +"2. Donating blood won't leave you low of blood; in reality you               still may have surplus blood even after donation."
           +"3. You will not faint or feel uncomfortable while donating blood. This is often a typical idea!"
           +"4. You will not get AIDS if you donate blood."
           +"5. If you want to consume alcohol, you'll be able to - on the consecutive day."
   +""
           +"Share love and gift life to someone who needs it the most. Donate blood!";

Comment: Use `\n` after every point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your resources do like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>   
  <string        name="myMessage">1. You won’t feel drained or tired if you drink fluids and have an honest meal\n
2. Donating blood won't leave you low of blood; in reality you \n 
etc .. 
</string> 

</resources>
```

then refer to it in the code in your activity  like the following :

```
email.setText(getString(R.string.myMessage));
```

and please give me some feedback

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 2):

Basically `\n` will print content to next line. so use it like below.

```
email.setText(text);
  text="1. You won’t feel drained or tired if you drink fluids and have an honest meal."
            +" \n 2. Donating blood won't leave you low of blood; in reality you            still may have surplus blood even after donation."
            +" \n 3. You will not faint or feel uncomfortable while donating blood. This is often a typical idea!"
            +" \n 4. You will not get AIDS if you donate blood."
            +" \n 5. If you want to consume alcohol, you'll be able to - on the consecutive day."
+""
            +" \n Share love and gift life to someone who needs it the most. Donate blood!";
```